# No unique column in source

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to implement batch processing in my SSIS package to send data from source to destination tables in batches. But in my source table there is no unique column that I can use for batch processing and I can't create one it is client's tables.

Also source queries contain `union` function as well, so how can I bring a unique column to my source table in SSIS and then implement batch processing?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15?

Comment: @Layla, please provide us with sample data and expected results, then we'll be able to assist easier...

Answer (score 1):

is it a one time thing or regular? if there is a date you can filter on that and just batch per day, month, year, or anything. If the package runs once every day you can just filter on that.

you say there is no unique column, but isnt there a combination of factors that make it unique? those work just as well.